# Getting the nth bit of a decimal number

Tags: computer-science, binary

I have a formula for decoding a 3-bit data object: $$T = 68 + 2 \sum_{i=0}^22^iTempA_i$$ where $TempA$ is the 3-bit object and $TempA_i$ is the $i$'th bit from the right.

I am trying to rewrite this as a formula for $TempA_i$ and I understand how to do this with a C program (I'm a a programmer, not a mathematician) but I can't determine if it is possible to write a non-conditional formula for this. I believe I need to use the modulus operator to achieve the formula, but I haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! There is also http://cs.stackexchange.com/ and http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ for all you computer science problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A formula for each digit:**

$Temp{A_0}=\dfrac{T-68}{2}\bmod2$

$Temp{A_1}=\big\lfloor\dfrac{T-68}{4}\big\rfloor\bmod2$

$Temp{A_2}=\big\lfloor\dfrac{T-68}{8}\big\rfloor\bmod2$

**The general formula is:**

$Temp{A_i}=\big\lfloor\dfrac{T-68}{2^{i+1}}\big\rfloor\bmod2$

---

In C, a simple integer-division can be used instead of the $\big\lfloor\dots\big\rfloor$:

```
TempA0 = ((T-68)/2)%2;
TempA1 = ((T-68)/4)%2;
TempA2 = ((T-68)/8)%2;
TempA[i] = ((T-68)/(1<<(i+1))%2;
```

As suggested in one of the comments below, bit-wise operations can be used instead:

```
TempA0 = ((T-68)>>1)&1;
TempA1 = ((T-68)>>2)&1;
TempA2 = ((T-68)>>3)&1;
TempA[i] = ((T-68)>>(i+1))&1;
```

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thank you for pointing that out. I believe that any decent compiler would apply this even without optimization enabled. In any case, since OP is a programmer, I'm sure that he or she will manage :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust - That is what I was using for my code-version, but for a simple mathematical formula I can't do bitwise operations. The original answer does exactly what I need, though.

Comment: @Gautam Gupta: of course you can do bitwise operations, they are well defined arithmetic operations on integers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I think OP means that these operations are not "normally" used in mathematical formulas.

Comment: @barakmanos: correct, I apologize if I confused you -- I wasn't sure what the correct terminology for that would be.

Comment: @Gautam Gupta: probably. There is no problem using them in mathematical expressions. Notation can be $\&$ or even $\land$ if the context makes it clear that the arguments are integer.

Comment: @GautamGupta: No problem. I added a general formula in case you needed one...